# Web-scraping with Rselenium. Doesn't return full information

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I want to scrape all comments, for example, from this web-page:
https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/10597708

My code:

```
library('RSelenium')
library('XML')
library('RCurl')

pJS <- phantom()
shell.exec(paste0("C:\\Users\\Daniil\\Desktop\\R-language,Python\\file.bat"))
Sys.sleep(10)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="chrome", port=4444)
remDr$open(silent=T)

Reviews <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id',value = 'reviews')
elem <- Reviews$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]
elemxml <- htmlTreeParse(elem, useInternalNodes=T)
e <- xpathApply(elemxml, "//*[(@class = 'row review')]", xmlValue)
```

But it returns me only 7 visible comments. How to extract all comments?
And in general what should I do in such situations(when only part information is visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot scrape something that isn't on the page. The comments are loaded in sets of 7. This is why you are not getting more than 7 comments.

If you want to get the other comments you'll have to navigate through the pages of comments. The list in the image below contains the button to select different pages, or go to the next page.

[image: Navigation buttons]

I'd recommend you use a loop to check if the next page button is on the page (if it isn't it means you have reached the last page of comments). In this loop you can scrape the data from these comments.